# To make use of Gmail with OAuth do we need to use the API or IMAP & SMTP?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I think in 2020 Google announced that they would be turning off access to LSA apps. That you need to use OAuth to access their services.

https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/03/less-secure-app-turn-off-suspended.html

Our application uses IMAP/SMTP/POP3 however to use these with oauth we need the full gmail scope ie (https://mail.google.com/). When we tried to get verified we were denied.

So we started building a gmail client using the gmail api with a more granular scope. however the docs themselves say to not use the api if you're making a client. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsbK3.png)

Is the correct approach to use IMAP/SMTP/POP3 libraries?

Comment: I have this same question. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I have not, I will let you know when I do. Tentatively my company is building out an email client using their API.